# Tagging exegetical questions

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a number of tags out there related to exegesis: 'exegesis', 'meaning', 'understanding', 'interpretation'. It's not clear to me from the names how these tags differ.

It seems likely that 1/3 or more of the questions on this site could end up falling into the "exegesis" category. Is a tag that covers that large a group useful?

Is there a better term we can use for 'meaning' that would distinguish questions like [one about the word 'ἐσφραγίσθητε'](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/123/sealed-in-eph-113) from [one about the meaning of an entire verse](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/meaning-of-where-there-is-a-dead-body-there-the-vultures-will-gather)? Perhaps 'definition'? Or lexical-something-or-other?

In general I'm wondering what tags might be useful for categorizing these types of questions.

Answer (score 5):

After a lengthy discussion in chat. I believe that [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis) should be removed and blacklisted. The reason for this is that a huge number of questions on this site are going to deal with exegesis and thus most of your questions should have the tag if tagged correctly. This makes the tag largely meaningless.

Comment: I agree.  Especially since exegesis questions are simply asking for the interpretation or translation.  That's kind of the point of this site.  I can go either way with leaving "hermeneutics" there, though.

Comment: On the other hand, I could maybe see someone wanting to search on multiple tags for, say, 'john' and 'exegesis' if perhaps they wanted to ignore questions of source criticism.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a paralleling a tag on programming language in stackoverflow. Suppose most questions were on C#. Would it be appropriate to tag questions on Java or PHP, but leave C# questions without the "C#" tag because that's the default? I would argue that this would be the wrong direction. Hermeneutics and Exegesis are two distinct topics and tagging the question with the topic to which you are referring would be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to decide if 'exegesis' was more like c# in that it will just have a lot of questions or if it's more like 'imperative-programming' where it could encompass so many questions (all Java, PHP, C#, etc... questions) that it becomes no longer useful.