# Can we get rid of the exegesis tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This problem was [predicted in the early days of the site](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/3555) and [dealt with a few years ago](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/562/3555) but has come up again. There are only 30 questions now tagged [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis), an apparently random bunch among the many exegesis questions here. The inconsistency irritates me. All of the 30 (except one that was migrated to meta) are also tagged with either a specific book, [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches), or one [hebrew-bible](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew-bible).

After some discussion in chat, I am planning to strip them all if there are no objections. If this becomes a (re-)recurrent problem, we could ask for [blacklisting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18898212#18898212). If people feel strongly that me bumping them all with tag edits is too disruptive, we could ask for re-[burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/272257).

I have also thought to revise the tag wiki to hopefully prevent its resurrection:

> Please do not use this tag.
>
> - If your question is about techniques of exegesis, use [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches).
> - If your question is requesting help with exegesis of a particular passage, tag it with the appropriate book.

I'm not sure if there's precedent for doing that sort of wiki, but I'm not sure what else we can do short of blacklisting.

Please voice objections/concerns/improvements to this plan.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Unfortunately, adding a "do not use" request won't stop questioners from merrily adding it to their Q's -- but it's worth a try! This would of course need to go into the `Excerpt` field, not the larger text area that gives the explanation.  If it works, we might find other tag candidates worthy of this treatment, too.

Comment: @Davïd I'm sure you're right. I think the biggest problem with this tag is that it potentially distracts the OP from the tags that **are** needed - e.g. my bullets above. I doubt this would help much but don't really feel like it's worth bothering the devs about at this point.

Comment: I should have thought for 17 seconds longer before commenting. We probably want the "`Please do not use this tag.`" bit to go in the "Excerpt" field, and your (very helpful) suggestions for more appropriate tagging in the body of the wiki. Would be a great combination, imo.

Comment: Apparently there was [some consensus around blacklisting](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/109/3555) way back when. Maybe this *is* a (re-)recurrent problem...

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is going to be different about discussion of this now so I'm channeling efforts to reviving the old post. I just pinged Jon there to see if we can get an actual blacklist on this one.

Comment: @Caleb Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Another useless tag: [tag:context].